# Random variable with value range and probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

A multiple choice test consists of 10 questions. For every question there are five possible answers, of which exactly one is correct. A test candidate answers all questions by chance.

**(a)** Give a suitable random variable with value range and probability distribution in order to work on part (b) with it.

**(b)** Determine (with intermediate steps) the probability that

(i) exactly 4 questions were answered correctly,

(ii) more than 4 questions have been answered correctly,

(iii) all tasks have been answered correctly,

(iv) at least half of the questions were answered correctly,

(v) at least 5 and at most 8 questions have been answered correctly.

$$$$

For (a) :

Let $X$ be a random variable that describes the number of correct answers out of $10$, right?

So is the range of the random variable $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ ?

For each correct answer the probability is equal to $\frac{1}{5}$ and each wrong answer has the probability $\frac{4}{5}$.

Do we have to calculate for each value of the random variable the corresponding probability?

Comment: Not really. You have to define a distribution. This discrete distribution can be defined with the help of a parameter $k$. Hint: The name of the distribution is binomial distribution. Does the hint help? Btw, the range is correct and also the single probabilities (1/5, 4/5).